# Getting method name related to a rest service

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I wanted to know if there exist a way of retrieving the actual method name associated to a rest service provided. Lets suppose my url is **http://localhost:8080/v1/mytesturl** now i want to retrieve the actual method name that is associated with this url.

Actually we are maintaining some key/value pair specific to the method that we have created and i need to make some checks based on the method name that gets executed using these values.

Plz let me know if there exist some way to do that..

Answer (score 1):

Simply get the method name from the [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/mytesturl")
    @ResponseBody        
    public String getMethodName() {
        return new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but not in the same method or class. Basically what i want is we have multiple services created with rest and i want to  write a filter and that filter requires the name of the method mapped to the provided url for reading a mapping which is having the method name as key.

Comment: @satishdikku You can use Class class of Reflection API to get all methods of a given class.

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution by using this

`Map<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> handlerMethods = RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerMethods();
         HandlerExecutionChain handler = RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandler(requestr);
         HandlerMethod handler1 = null;
         if(Objects.nonNull(handler)){
             handler1 = (HandlerMethod) handler.getHandler();
           handler1.getMethod().getName()
        }`

this provide me with what i wanted..